# Why is my Rode NT1 Mic making noise

Tags: microphone, noise

I have a [Rode - NT1 Mic](http://www.rode.com/microphones/nt1). I bought it several months ago and I haven't used it that much. I put it in the box along with moisture absorbent.

Now I took it out and realized that it is making some kind of noise. [Here is the noise it makes](https://soundcloud.com/ako-kaman/microphone).

I am using a [Focusrite - Scarlett 2i2](https://us.focusrite.com/usb-audio-interfaces/scarlett-2i2/specifications) sound card with it.

Any idea what is wrong? Is it because of the Mic, cable or the sound card?

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. Thanks for posting the sound sample, it's literally identical to my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the cable and the audio interface with a different mic and found out that my mic is faulty.

I sent it to a locale Rode distributer and they fixed it for me, for free.

Comment: was there any information on what was wrong?

Comment: @BrDaHa Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1):

The standard troubleshooting methodology with an issue like this would be:

1. test the microphone and audio interface with a different microphone cable and see if that fixes the issue
2. if not, then test the microphone and cable with a different audio interface and see if that fixes the issue
3. if not, then your microphone might be faulty

If you don’t have that gear around, maybe you can take the microphone to a friend’s studio or a musical instrument store and plug the microphone into a system there and see if you still get the noise.

Another avenue you can explore is if your computer runs on batteries, try running it on batteries with the audio interface and microphone plugged in, to isolate the system from any power line noise.